# Structure sheaf of derived intersection

Tags: model-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras

Everything is over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ two closed dg subschemes over a dg scheme $Z$. I am trying to understand the structure sheaf of the derived intersection of $X$ and $Y$ in $Z$.

The problem I'm having is that I don't understand the meaning of the derived tensor product. More precisely, if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ were affine and represented by commutative dg algebras concentrated in non positive degrees (the underlying complex is a cochain complex) $A$, $B$, $C$ respectively, then the derived tensor intersection should be represented by the cdga $A \stackrel{L}{\otimes}_{C} B$. The question here is: where are we deriving the tensor product? I guess there is a model structure on $\text{cdga}^{\leq 0}_k$, but I couldn't find any explicit reference (nLab has a structure on $\text{cdga}^{\geq 0}_k$, and most of the other references work with simplicial commutative rings; I found some papers that talk about restricting the model structure on a symmetric monoidal category $M$ to monoids in $M$, but that's very general, and I was hoping to find more concrete references).

The general case is a problem for the same reason. The structure dg sheaf should be $\mathcal{O}_{X} \stackrel{L}{\otimes}_{\mathcal{O}_Z} \mathcal{O}_Y$, but once again I don't understand where the derived tensor product is taken. Does the category of sheaves of non positively graded cdga inherit a model structure we use to compute this tensor product?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. Fibrations are surjective in strictly positive degrees, and cofibrations are retracts of maps which are freely generated on the underlying graded algebras. The structure transfers by adjunction from the projective model structure on non-negatively graded chain complexes.

Comment: If you replace $B$ with any $B'$ such that $C \to B'$ is flat on the underlying graded algebras, the derived tensor product in $cdga^{\le 0}$ is just $A\otimes_CB'$.

Comment: Thanks. Just two clarifications: (1) as you are talking about chain complexes, I assume that for cdgas with underlying cochain complex fibrations are surjective in strictly negative degree, right? (2) What about the sheaf case? Do we have a projective model structure even on (cochain complexes) $Ch^{\leq 0}(Sh_{k}(Z))$, where $Sh_{k}(Z)$ are sheaves of $k$-modules over $Z$, and we transfer it to the category of sheaves of cdgas on $Z$?

Comment: (1) yes. (2) Basically, yes. It's not much of an issue in this case, because you can take derived tensor product as a presheaf of algebras, and find it's already a hypersheaf on the site of affine opens.

Comment: For (2): because functors into $\text{cdga}^{\leq 0}$ from the site of affine opens are a model category in this case, and it happens that the tensor product is already a sheaf on this site (even if it need not be a priori), right?

Comment: Yes. There are general ways of putting model structures on categories of diagrams in model categories. The reason this is a hypersheaf is essentially that its homology groups are quasi-coherent, so are themselves hypersheaves.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers!